# Error in static function

Tags: php, laravel-5.3

I have an array like this (inside a controller):

```
$nd = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

I'm using a function to create another array:

```
public static crearNodo($id){
    $users = DB::table('users')->select('id','name')->where('id', $id)->get();

    $nodo = "";
    foreach ($users as $user){
        $nodo = "{id: ". $user->id .", label: '". $user->name ."'}";
    }

    return $nodo;
}
```

And I call that funtion on this way:

```
for ($i=0; $i < count($nd); $i++) {
    $id = $nd[$i];

    if($i == 0) {
        $nodos = panelController::crearNodo($id);
    }
    else{
        $nodos .= ",,".panelController::crearNodo($id);
    }
}
```

But I'm getting this error:

> syntax error, unexpected 'crearNodo' (T_STRING), expecting variable
>   (T_VARIABLE)

I would like you to help me out, i don't know where is my mistake.

Comment: You need the word `function` in front of a function name.

Comment: That's really dummy, sorry all and thank you for the help @KIKOSoftware. In my defense, I'm here for 6 hours...

Comment: It happens to us all... I know exactly why it happens, and how it feels. Time for a break?

Comment: Save your `",,".panelController::crearNodo($id)` into a variable then use that variable.

Comment: Is `$nodos` going to be used with javascript? I only ask because what you're doing looks very inefficient and there is probably a much better way to go about it.